# How to add leading zeros?

Tags: r, formatting, number-formatting, r-faq

I have a set of data which looks something like this:

```
anim <- c(25499,25500,25501,25502,25503,25504)
sex  <- c(1,2,2,1,2,1)
wt   <- c(0.8,1.2,1.0,2.0,1.8,1.4)
data <- data.frame(anim,sex,wt)

data
   anim sex  wt anim2
1 25499   1 0.8     2
2 25500   2 1.2     2
3 25501   2 1.0     2
4 25502   1 2.0     2
5 25503   2 1.8     2
6 25504   1 1.4     2
```

I would like a zero to be added before each animal id:

```
data
   anim sex  wt anim2
1 025499   1 0.8     2
2 025500   2 1.2     2
3 025501   2 1.0     2
4 025502   1 2.0     2
5 025503   2 1.8     2
6 025504   1 1.4     2
```

And for interest sake, what if I need to add two or three zeros before the animal id's?

Comment: Suppose you want to add n zeros before animal ids you just need to do `data$anim = paste(rep(0, n), data$anim, sep = "")`

Comment: When you say you want to "add zeros", you presumably don't want to convert your integer columns to string/categorical in order to add the zero-padding inside the data itself, you want to keep them integer and **only print leading zeros when rendering output**.

Answer (score 769, accepted):

The short version: use [`formatC`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/formatC) or [`sprintf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/sprintf).

---

The longer version:

There are several functions available for formatting numbers, including adding leading zeroes.  Which one is best depends upon what other formatting you want to do.

The example from the question is quite easy since all the values have the same number of digits to begin with, so let's try a harder example of making powers of 10 width 8 too.

```
anim <- 25499:25504
x <- 10 ^ (0:5)
```

---

**[`paste`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/paste)** (and it's variant `paste0`) are often the first string manipulation functions that you come across.  They aren't really designed for manipulating numbers, but they can be used for that.  In the simple case where we always have to prepend a single zero, `paste0` is the best solution.

```
paste0("0", anim)
## [1] "025499" "025500" "025501" "025502" "025503" "025504"
```

For the case where there are a variable number of digits in the numbers, you have to manually calculate how many zeroes to prepend, which is horrible enough that you should only do it out of morbid curiosity.

---

**[`str_pad`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/topics/str_pad)** from `stringr` works similarly to `paste`, making it more explicit that you want to pad things.

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(anim, 6, pad = "0")
## [1] "025499" "025500" "025501" "025502" "025503" "025504"
```

Again, it isn't really designed for use with numbers, so the harder case requires a little thinking about.  We ought to just be able to say "pad with zeroes to width 8", but look at this output:

```
str_pad(x, 8, pad = "0")
## [1] "00000001" "00000010" "00000100" "00001000" "00010000" "0001e+05"
```

You need to set the scientific penalty [option](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/options) so that numbers are always formatted using fixed notation (rather than scientific notation).

```
library(withr)
with_options(
  c(scipen = 999), 
  str_pad(x, 8, pad = "0")
)
## [1] "00000001" "00000010" "00000100" "00001000" "00010000" "00100000"
```

---

**[`stri_pad`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/topics/stri_pad.html)** in `stringi` works exactly like `str_pad` from `stringr`.

---

**[`formatC`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/formatC)** is an interface to the C function [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).  Using it requires some knowledge of the arcana of that underlying function (see link).  In this case, the important points are the `width` argument, `format` being `"d"` for "integer", and a `"0"` `flag` for prepending zeroes.

```
formatC(anim, width = 6, format = "d", flag = "0")
## [1] "025499" "025500" "025501" "025502" "025503" "025504"
formatC(x, width = 8, format = "d", flag = "0")
## [1] "00000001" "00000010" "00000100" "00001000" "00010000" "00100000"
```

This is my favourite solution, since it is easy to tinker with changing the width, and the function is powerful enough to make other formatting changes.

---

**[`sprintf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/sprintf)** is an interface to the C function of the same name; like `formatC` but with a different syntax.

```
sprintf("%06d", anim)
## [1] "025499" "025500" "025501" "025502" "025503" "025504"
sprintf("%08d", x)
## [1] "00000001" "00000010" "00000100" "00001000" "00010000" "00100000"
```

The main advantage of `sprintf` is that you can embed formatted numbers inside longer bits of text.

```
sprintf(
  "Animal ID %06d was a %s.", 
  anim, 
  sample(c("lion", "tiger"), length(anim), replace = TRUE)
)
## [1] "Animal ID 025499 was a tiger." "Animal ID 025500 was a tiger."
## [3] "Animal ID 025501 was a lion."  "Animal ID 025502 was a tiger."
## [5] "Animal ID 025503 was a tiger." "Animal ID 025504 was a lion."
```

See also [goodside's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812607/134830).

---

For completeness it is worth mentioning the other formatting functions that are occasionally useful, but have no method of prepending zeroes.

**[`format`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/format)**, a generic function for formatting any kind of object, with a method for numbers.  It works a little bit like `formatC`, but with yet another interface.

**[`prettyNum`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/prettyNum)** is yet another formatting function, mostly for creating manual axis tick labels.  It works particularly well for wide ranges of numbers.

The **`scales`** package has several functions such as [`percent`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/topics/percent_format), [`date_format`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/topics/date_format) and [`dollar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/topics/dollar_format) for specialist format types.

Comment: thanks alot for the great help. I used formatC to add leading zeros to my anim and it worked well.

Comment: formatC(number or vector, width = 6, format = "d", flag = "0") worked well (R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)). Thanks.

Comment: using formatC() in the way described above didn't work for me. It added spaces instead of zeroes. Did I do something wrong? I'm using R version 3.1.1.

Comment: @user1816679 Sounds like you forgot `flag = "0"`.

Comment: Nope. Input: `formatC('1', width = 3, format = 'd', flag = '0')`
Output: `[1] "  1"`
  

Edit: I tried it without the quotes and it worked

Comment: `formatC` is designed to format *numbers*. If you pass a string to it, then of course you will get unexpected results.  The function should really warn about receiving a silly input.

Comment: Thank you for listing all the possibilities even if they seem to be "the same". I wanted to pad my numbers to equal width, no matter how many I have, and I was able to use formatC with `width=ceiling(log(nr.vars, base=10))` for it. I wouldn't have been able to do this with the printf syntax (or if there is a way, I don't know it).

Comment: @rumtscho Try `sprintf("%8.2f", 10 ^ (1:10))`. Also, `log10` is easier than `log(base = 10)`.

Comment: @RichieCotton I must admit I have almost no knowledge of the sprintf syntax. How does your suggestion work, and most importantly, where does it take the variable which determines how many zeroes to use?

Comment: The Details section of the `?sprintf` help page describes this.  "m.n: Two numbers separated by a period, denoting the field width (m) and the precision (n)."

Answer (score 256):

For a general solution that works regardless of how many digits are in `data$anim`, use the `sprintf` function. It works like this:

```
sprintf("%04d", 1)
# [1] "0001"
sprintf("%04d", 104)
# [1] "0104"
sprintf("%010d", 104)
# [1] "0000000104"
```

In your case, you probably want: `data$anim <- sprintf("%06d", data$anim)`

Comment: Note that `sprintf` converts numeric to string (character).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to make a 13-digits number to 14-digits (adding leading zero). This function doesn't seems to work for this case. It gives me an arror: Error in sprintf("%020d", 4000100000104) : 
  invalid format '%020d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try: sprintf("%014.0f", 4000100000104)

Comment: sprintf is not available for R 3.4.1

Comment: Yes it is. It's unchanged since version 1.5.0.

Comment: I had a weird experience where a colleague using Windows would have `sprintf(` print leading spaces while my Mac was printing leading zeros. We switched to `stringr::str_pad(`

Answer (score 39):

Expanding on @goodside's repsonse:

In some cases you may want to pad a string with zeros (e.g. fips codes or other numeric-like factors). In OSX/Linux:

```
> sprintf("%05s", "104")
[1] "00104"
```

But because `sprintf()` calls the OS's C `sprintf()` command, discussed [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/pad-leading-zeros-in-front-of-strings-td4630964.html), in Windows 7 you get a different result:

```
> sprintf("%05s", "104")
[1] "  104"
```

So on Windows machines the work around is:

```
> sprintf("%05d", as.numeric("104"))
[1] "00104"
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this solution no longer works for me on Linux. @kdauria's `str_pad` is now my go to.

Answer (score 36):

`str_pad` from the `stringr` package is an alternative.

```
anim = 25499:25504
str_pad(anim, width=6, pad="0")
```

Comment: Be very careful with `str_pad` as it can lead to unexpected results.    
```i.num = 600000```;    
```str_pad(i.num, width = 7, pad = "0")```    will give you "006e+05" and not "0600000"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalizable base R function:

```
pad_left <- function(x, len = 1 + max(nchar(x)), char = '0'){

    unlist(lapply(x, function(x) {
        paste0(
            paste(rep(char, len - nchar(x)), collapse = ''),
            x
        )
    }))
}

pad_left(1:100)
```

I like `sprintf` but it comes with caveats like:

> however the actual implementation will follow the C99 standard and fine details (especially the behaviour under user error) may depend on the platform

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative for adding leading to 0s to strings such as [CUSIPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSIP) which can sometimes look like a number and which many applications such as Excel will corrupt and remove the leading 0s or convert them to scientific notation.

When I tried the answer provided by @metasequoia the vector returned had leading spaces and not `0`s. This was the same problem mentioned by @user1816679 -- and removing the quotes around the `0` or changing from `%d` to `%s` did not make a difference either. FYI, I am using RStudio Server running on an Ubuntu Server. This little two-step solution worked for me:

`gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "0", x = sprintf(fmt = "%09s", ids[,CUSIP]))`

using the `%>%` pipe function from the `magrittr` package it could look like this:

`sprintf(fmt = "%09s", ids[,CUSIP]) %>% gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "0", x = .)`

I'd prefer a one-function solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

For other circumstances in which you want the number string to be consistent, I made a function.

Someone may find this useful:

```
idnamer<-function(x,y){#Alphabetical designation and number of integers required
    id<-c(1:y)
    for (i in 1:length(id)){
         if(nchar(id[i])<2){
            id[i]<-paste("0",id[i],sep="")
         }
    }
    id<-paste(x,id,sep="")
    return(id)
}
idnamer("EF",28)
```

Sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
data$anim <- sapply(0, paste0,data$anim)
```