# Do not want scientific notation on plot axis

Tags: math, r, graphics

I regularly do all kinds of scatter plots in R using the `plot` command.

Sometimes both, sometimes only one of the plot axes is labelled in scientific notation. I do not understand when R makes the decision to switch to scientific notation. Surprisingly, it often prints numbers which no sane human would write in scientific notation when labelling a plot, for example it labels 5 as 5e+00. Let's say you have a log-axis going up to 1000, scientific notation is unjustified with such "small" numbers.

I would like to suppress that behaviour, I always want R to display integer values.  Is this possible?

I tried `options(scipen=10)` but then it starts writing 5.0 instead of 5, while on the other axis 5 is still 5 etc. How can I have pure integer values in my R plots?

I am using R 2.12.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: There's more advice on formatting numbers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r/5816779

Answer (score 61):

Use `options(scipen=5)` or some other high enough number.  The scipen option determines how likely R is to switch to scientific notation, the higher the value the less likely it is to switch.  Set the option before making your plot, if it still has scientific notation, set it to a higher number.

Comment: If you had actually read my original question, you would have read that "I tried options(scipen=10) but then it starts writing 5.0 instead of 5". And that I want numbers written as 5 not 5.0, and so on.

Comment: @gojira But did you try other values of `scipen`? Did you try `scipen=5`?

Comment: You are right, I missed that you had already tried that.  Others have pointed out that you can use the axis function to put exactly what you want where you want it with functions like format, sprintf, and pretty.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `format` or `formatC` to, ahem, format your axis labels.

For whole numbers, try

```
x <- 10 ^ (1:10)
format(x, scientific = FALSE)
formatC(x, digits = 0, format = "f")
```

If the numbers are convertable to actual integers (i.e., not too big), you can also use

```
formatC(x, format = "d")
```

How you get the labels onto your axis depends upon the plotting system that you are using.

Comment: This isn't particularly helpful because the OP had already stated they are using `plot()`

Comment: @PeterEllis How it's not helpful? If using `plot` tou got control over axis, see other answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968136/168747 (line starts with `axis(`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `axis()` command for that, eg :

```
x <- 1:100000
y <- 1:100000
marks <- c(0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000)
plot(x,y,log="x",yaxt="n",type="l")
axis(2,at=marks,labels=marks)
```

gives :

[image]

EDIT : if you want to have all of them in the same format, you can use the solution of @Richie to get them :

```
x <- 1:100000
y <- 1:100000
format(y,scientific=FALSE)
plot(x,y,log="x",yaxt="n",type="l")
axis(2,at=marks,labels=format(marks,scientific=FALSE))
```

Comment: I just had the idea of using axis and strings instead of numbers to get "pure integers" (i.e. quote the numbers")?

Comment: @Henrik : works as well, but the idea about using format is that you can give one vector for both position and labels. And you can reuse that one in different plots. I adjusted my code to show that.

Comment: In rstudio, if you import a dataset and do
    train_sample_10k = format(train_sample_10k,scientific=FALSE) 
and reload, it will change the scientific notations.

Comment: @mixdev Obviously. If you check `?format`, you see that it returns a character string with the notations. If you reload, you overwrite the character string with the original values. `format()` doesn't set some format attribute, it generates text. Hence the use as a value for the argument `labels`

Comment: How have I never seen the `scientific = FALSE` part of this answer/the documentation before  `format(x, scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE, big.mark = ',')` is a life changer

Answer (score 14):

Try this.  I purposely broke out various parts so you can move things around.

```
library(sfsmisc)

#Generate the data
x <- 1:100000
y <- 1:100000

#Setup the plot area
par(pty="m", plt=c(0.1, 1, 0.1, 1), omd=c(0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9))

#Plot a blank graph without completing the x or y axis
plot(x, y, type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", log = "x", col="blue")
mtext(side=3, text="Test Plot", line=1.2, cex=1.5)

#Complete the x axis
eaxis(1, padj=-0.5, cex.axis=0.8)
mtext(side=1, text="x", line=2.5)

#Complete the y axis and add the grid
aty <- seq(par("yaxp")[1], par("yaxp")[2], (par("yaxp")[2] - par("yaxp")[1])/par("yaxp")[3])
axis(2, at=aty, labels=format(aty, scientific=FALSE), hadj=0.9, cex.axis=0.8, las=2)
mtext(side=2, text="y", line=4.5)
grid()

#Add the line last so it will be on top of the grid
lines(x, y, col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could try [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lattice):

```
require(lattice)
x <- 1:100000
y <- 1:100000
xyplot(y~x, scales=list(x = list(log = 10)), type="l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `R` `graphics` package has the function `axTicks` that returns the tick locations of the ticks that the `axis` and `plot` functions would set automatically. The other answers given to this question define the tick locations manually which might not be convenient in some situations.

```
myTicks = axTicks(1)
axis(1, at = myTicks, labels = formatC(myTicks, format = 'd'))
```

A minimal example would be

```
plot(10^(0:10), 0:10, log = 'x', xaxt = 'n')
myTicks = axTicks(1)
axis(1, at = myTicks, labels = formatC(myTicks, format = 'd'))
```

There is also an `log` parameter in the `axTicks` function but in this situation it does not need to be set to get the proper logarithmic axis tick location.

Answer (score -3):

Normally setting axis limit @ max of your variable is enough

```
a <- c(0:1000000)
b <- c(0:1000000)

plot(a, b, ylim = c(0, max(b)))
```

Comment: Nope, it's not, and your answer doesn't bother to explain how this would have any effect.