# How to remove e-notation on y axis when plotting graph with R?

Tags: r, graph

I am plotting a graph with log scale on y-axis. It starts from 0.001 and stops at 700.

The problem is y-axis is written with scientific notation. And I don't want that.

How can I have:

```
0.001    0.1     10      1000
```

instead of:

```
1e-03   1e-01   1e+01   1e+03
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963047/do-not-want-scientific-notation-on-plot-axis