# While plotting a Barplot my number on Y axis atomatically gets converted to exponential form. how can I avoid that

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my barplot

```
ggplot( diamonds, aes(clarity , price) ) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

and I get this as my output
[image]

I am not able to convert the Y axis exponential display to regular numbers

[Do not want scientific notation on plot axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963047/do-not-want-scientific-notation-on-plot-axis)

I have tried the scipen and format function as well

```
ggplot( diamonds, aes(clarity , b) , options(scipen=10)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

b <- diamonds$price
formatC(b , format = "d")

a <- ggplot( diamonds, aes(clarity , b)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This is not a duplicate so kindly don't mark as duplicate as i have tried all the other options I came accross.
Please help if I am making any mistake or suggest an answer.

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. Your mistake was not searching for ggplot - the answer you linked is for base r. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/14564102/5316882

Comment: Does `ggplot` take an argument `options`? I always assumed that that option went on the *outside* (which worked for me). @anotherfred's link is your key, I think, and it can be a nice trick to assign a custom function to `scale_y_continuous(..., labels=myfunc)` where your `myfunc` makes it look exactly the way you want. (Well-asked question, btw ... though it does use `b` before it is defined.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
ggplot( diamonds, aes(clarity , price) ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```