# How can I change plotted numbers from scientific notation to standard form in an rpart regression tree plot?

Tags: r, rpart

I am using the `rpart.plot` package to plot a regression tree. How can  change the numbers from scientific notation into standard form at the bottom of the tree? For example, I want to change `14e+3` to `14000`.

This is the code I am using:

```
library(rpart.plot)
rpart.plot(tm1, type=5, digits = 2, fallen.leaves = T)
```

And here is the result:

[image: Regression Tree Example]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I attached the regression tree plot. I hope this helps

Comment: That doesn't allow us to run and test the code for possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963047/do-not-want-scientific-notation-on-plot-axis

Comment: does options(scipen=999) do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one, because the package author decided to hard code in the scientific notation.

If we review the [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/rpart.plot/src/R/lib.rpart.plot.R#sym-format0), there is a
function `rpart.plot:::format0` that formats any values between `0.001` and `9999`.

So one approach, is to create a copy that over-writes those default values and assign it into the `rpart.plot` namespace.

First, an example tree:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(rpart.plot)
fit <- rpart(carrier ~ origin + distance, data = flights[flights$carrier %in% c("UA","AA","DL"),])
rpart.plot(fit, type = 5, digits = 2, fallen.leaves = TRUE, extra = 101)
```

[image]

Note the scientific notation.

Now, we'll create the copy and call it `myformat0`. We need to use `:::` for a couple of functions because they aren't exported from `rpart.plot`. Note that I replaced the `9999` with `100000`, but you can use whatever number you want.

```
myformat0 <- function(x, digits=2)
{
    rpart.plot:::check.integer.scalar(digits)
    if(digits == 0)
        digits <- getOption("digits")
    if(digits >= 0)
        rpart.plot:::formate(x, digits, smallest=.001, largest=100000)
    else
        sapply(x, format, digits=-digits)
}
```

Now we need to assign our custom function into the `rpart.plot` namespace. We can use `assignInNamespace`:

```
assignInNamespace("format0", myformat0, ns = "rpart.plot")
```

And now the plot:

```
rpart.plot(fit, type = 5, digits = 2, fallen.leaves = TRUE, extra = 101)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help with this. This is so helpful