uploaded data file changes numeric format
enter image description here
enter image description here
When I upload this csv file which shows BoxOffice as a full number (1), it changed the format for BoxOffice to be exponential (2) which is ruining my plots later on. How do I get it to stay in the same format
The only way it showing the way I want is by switching it to character but I need it as a numeric variable
plot(movies$Budget, movies$BoxOffice, xlab = "Budget ($)", ylab = "Box Office ($)", 
     main = "Movie Budget and Box Office Earnings", pch = 20) 

This is the code I used, how can I adjust the scale to make it more ideal?

The full numbers are still there, they're just being shown differently by the formatting of the data.frame when printed. This is probably better fixed at the point of making your plots, where you could change how the axis is displayed. If you could show an example plot code, that would help.

plot(movies$Budget, movies$BoxOffice, xlab = "Budget ($)", ylab = "Box Office ($)", main = "Movie Budget and Box Office Earnings", pch = 20)
this is the code I used, how can I adjust the scale to make it more ideal?

You might find this similar prior question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963047/do-not-want-scientific-notation-on-plot-axis
