# How to read numeric values as factors in R?

Tags: r, csv, r-factor

I have a data frame A which has numeric column like:

```
zip code
00601
00602
00607
```

and so on.

If I read this in R using read.csv, they are read as numeric entities. I want them as factors.

I tried converting them back to factor using

```
A <- as.factor(A)
```

But this removes starting zeroes and make A like

```
zip code
601
602
607
```

I do not want this. I want to save zeroes.

Comment: Are you sure they're numeric?

Comment: @Thomas if stored in `R` as `00607` they surely are not. It's strange bacause the OP says both `they are read as numeric` and `I have a data frame A which has numeric column like: zip code 00601 ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `colClasses` in your `read.csv` call to read them in as character or factor: `read.csv(*, colClasses="factor")`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add leading zeros - as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r). This first converts to a character class. Then, you can change this to a factor, which maintains the leading zeros.

#### Example

```
A <- data.frame("zip code"=c(00601,00602,00607))
class(A$zip.code) #numeric
A$zip.code <- sprintf("%05d", A$zip.code)
class(A$zip.code) #character
A$zip.code <- as.factor(A$zip.code)
class(A$zip.code) #factor
```

Resulting in:

```
> A$zip.code
[1] 00601 00602 00607
Levels: 00601 00602 00607
```

Writing `A` as a .csv file

```
write.csv(A, "tmp.csv")
```

results in

```
"","zip.code"
"1","00601"
"2","00602"
"3","00607"
```

Comment: Hi Marc, Thank you for an alternative solution. I am getting to know a lot of functions. Just one doubt, if I write this data frame uaing write.csv(), zip.code is taken as numeric vector (it automatically removes zeroes in starting, no matter zip is factor or character in R console). How do I write it as it is (means with zeroes in starting)??

Comment: @AyushRajSingh - In my case, when I write a .csv file, `zip.code`is taken as text. I have added what my output looks like in the answer.

Comment: I tried your same example, but when I write it, zeroes are getting disappeared. What may be the problem? By "write it": I mean, when I open it in Excel after using write.csv().

Comment: OK, that's an Excel problem. In Excel, there is actually a format for zip codes: Highlight column > Format Cells > Special > Zip Code

Answer (score 0):

everything without any text qualifier is (attempted to be) read as numeric, so the issue is basically to know how your data (in case `00607`) is stored on the flat text file. If without text qualifier, you can either follow the suggestion of @Hong Ooi or use

```
read.csv(*, colClasses="character")
```

and then convert each column accordingly (in case you don' want/need all of them to `factor`). Once you have a character vector (a data.frame column) converting it to factor is just straightforward

```
> zipCode <- c("00601", "00602", "00607")
> factor(zipCode)
[1] 00601 00602 00607
Levels: 00601 00602 00607
```