# R: keep leading zero

Tags: r

I have a dataset in .csv format. In my dataset there is one column which is leading with zero like this  "05","02". i am trying to import .csv file using read.csv in R. It read successfully but it remove the leading zero. 
  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could specify `colClasses='character' in `read.csv` (not tested though)

Comment: See also [**how to add leading zeros**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r) when the data is already read.

Answer (score 1):

If all the data in the column are of the same length, you can do `paste0("0", NAME)`.

If variable length, try [formatC](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/formatC) like so: `formatC(NAME, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")`.

In the latter example, 'd' refers to 'integer' and 'width' can be changed as desired.

Comment: This solution is good, and works as long as the length of the data is known in advance. That said, if one does not know the length of the data(argument) in advance, it can fail.