# R how add leading zero instead of white space

Tags: r, whitespace, leading-zero

first of all, I have read through the following posts ([R: keep leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801195/r-keep-leading-zero), [and again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063793/how-to-use-sprintf-function-to-add-leading-0-instead-of-spaces-to-character), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros/8267036#8267036), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043162/r-excel-leading-zeroes/24044769#24044769).), and my question is not answered by any of them.

I try to add a leading zero to the `ID` column. The file is imported from excel, I am not sure how to upload to here. Probably not able to replicate the process to you.

When I use any of the following code to add a leading zero

```
formatC(data$col,width=5,format="s",flag="0")
sprintf("%05s",data$col)
gsub('\\s','0',data$col)
```

all of them gave me a whitespace before the string, instead of a zero. e.g.`" 4097"`

I also try to trim down any space`trimws(sort$DlrNbr, which = c("both", "left", "right"))`, and re-try add leading zero, still failed.

Do you have any idea what is going on? Any insight is helpful!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the wrong format with sprintf.

Using `sprintf('%05d', data$col)` should do the trick (notice the `d`, which is used to format integers, instead of the `s`, which is used to format strings).

You can find more details in the help page: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/sprintf

Comment: Hey Lucacerone, thank you so much. You solve my problem. I didnt aware I can convert to numeric and add leading zero. thank you!

Comment: Still not working. sprintf('%02s', "1") returns " 1", not "01".

Comment: df$col<- gsub(" ", "0",df$col ). When set at default I got blanks instead of 0 so I just did a replace.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(data$col, 5, pad = "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use paste, i.e.:

```
library(data.table)
data[, col := paste0('0', col)]
```

Comment: Hey, because it should be a fixed width, some id is like 45009, they dont need a leading zero. thank you so much though