# sprintf failing with numeric over 9 digits in length

Tags: r, printf

This is pretty straight forward:

```
> sprintf("%013d",150025901)
[1] "0000150025901"
> sprintf("%013d",8150025901)
Error in sprintf("%013d", 8150025901) : 
  invalid format '%013d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

ultimately I need to use this on a 12 digit number, but I just removed digits until sprintf would stop returning that error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's because `%d` is for integer values and `is.integer(8150025901) ## [1] FALSE` and `is.double(8150025901)
## [1] TRUE`.  At some point the large integer is no longer an integer in R.  But like I said, I don't know for sure.

Comment: on my (and, I suspect most R systems) `.Machine$integer.max` == `2147483647` so you're definitely in `double` territory and out of `d` use.

Comment: Confirmed `.Machine$integer.max < 8150025901 ## [1] TRUE`.  So you may need to switch to `format()` instead of `sprintf()`

Comment: Try `library(stringr); str_pad(8150025901, 13, pad = "0")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding leading zeros using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`8150025901` is too big for an integer, which maxes out at `2147483647`

You can use sprintf with a double instead of an int and get the desired results.  The exact code for this would be:

```
sprintf("%013.000f",8150025901)
```

*However*, it is important to note that--while R will not give you an explicit error or warning--if you try to do this with numbers more than ~15 digits, you can get unpredictable results.

This is because doubles in R have 53-bit precision, and 10^15 < 2^53 < 10^16.  That means the rounding error in the number you are converting is greater than one for 16-digits, so (for example) `sprintf("%013.000f",10^16)` and `sprintf("%013.000f",10^16+1)` both produce `"10000000000000000"` due to rounding