# how to create sequence of numbers in same digit with a character in R

Tags: r

I'd like to make a sequence of numbers with a character in R as below.

```
[H01, H02, H03, ... , H24]
```

I can only generate numbering characters like

```
[H1, H2, H3, ... , H24]
```

with a command

```
paste0("H", 1:24)
```

any tips for this?

Comment: Check out `?sprintf`, e.g. `sprintf("%02dH", 1:24)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprintf` is similar with `printf` of C, so you can control the format exactly as below:

```
sprintf("H%02d", 1:24)
[1] "H01" "H02" "H03" "H04" "H05" "H06" "H07" "H08" "H09" "H10" "H11" "H12" "H13" "H14" "H15" "H16" "H17" "H18" "H19" "H20" "H21"
[22] "H22" "H23" "H24"
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r).

Comment: Just to nitpick, I'd say that the R `sprintf` is more similar to the C `sprintf`, since it creates an object instead of writing on a file/connection (unless you `print` the result of course).

Comment: @nicola agree, C' buffer  .vs. R' object :)