# how create a sequence of strings with different numbers in R

Tags: r, sequence

I just cant figure it out how to create a vector in which the strings are constant but the numbers are not. For example:

```
c("raster[1]","raster[2]","raster[3]")
```

I'd like to use something like `seq(raster[1],raster[99], by=1)`, but this does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Post your reproducible attempts so we can help you.  If you are constructing code with strings for later evaluation, that's the wrong way to do things.

Comment: You can consider looking at answers here for nice discussion and alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `sprintf` function should also work:

```
rasters <- sprintf("raster[%s]",seq(1:99))
head(rasters)
[1] "raster[1]" "raster[2]" "raster[3]" "raster[4]" "raster[5]" "raster[6]"
```

As suggested by Richard Scriven, `%d` is more efficient than `%s`. So, if you were working with a longer sequence, it would be more appropriate to use:

```
rasters <- sprintf("raster[%d]",seq(1:99))
```

Comment: `%d` might b more appropriate.  I think with `%s`, the sequence is being coerced to character first and then applied.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @RichardScriven, you're on to something. The usage of `%s` definitely makes R coerce the digits into characters. So, `%d` is more efficient. I will add it to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hate to comment on this but i have the opposite problem where "Ballroom 2-4" would ideally become "Ballroom 2, Ballroom 3, Ballroom 4". Can anyone help me with this ? I already asked the question a couple of days ago on stackoverflow (still waiting for a suggestion)

Comment: @KarimKardous, you may be looking for `paste0(sprintf('Ballroom %d', 1:4), collapse = ", ")`.

Comment: Yes your answer makes sense, is there a DYNAMIC way of coding this ? what if the next row's value (it's a dataframe) is "Ballroom 5-8" ?

Comment: @KarimKardous, I can't really think of a dynamic way of doing this. But [here](https://gist.github.com/AbdouSeck/1f024fb740fd6d66038f6ce6389023a8) is a script that tries to answer your question.

Comment: I think this gets me far enough in the process. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 18):

We can do

```
paste0("raster[", 1:6, "]")
# [1] "raster[1]" "raster[2]" "raster[3]" "raster[4]" "raster[5]" "raster[6]"
```

Comment: thanks for both answers! both work for me. It is a pity I could not decide which is best, so i just tossed a coin to choose one, though it should be best if at least someone has the mark. I up voted both, though.

Comment: @Aguscamacho no problem; there's usually more than one way to solve a problem. I wasn't aware of the `sprintf` method either so I've learnt something too.

Comment: @Aguscamacho, I think `paste0` is syntactically better than `sprintf` as it's easier to guess what the function aims to achieve just by looking at its name?