# R code to generate unique ID with prefix?

Tags: r

I have a table called "pipel" that contains more than 10,000 rows. I would like to add an ID column to assign a unique ID for each row. The unique ID must be 30 digits long and starts with "AKM_CC_Test_". I used the code below as a starting point but not sure how to format it to add the prefix and make it 30 digits long.

```
id <- rownames(pipel)
pipel <- cbind(id=id, pipel)
```

For example first row ID will need to look like this AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000001

Comment: Try `stringr::str_pad("1", 30, pad="0")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `sprintf()`.  This creates a 30 character string beginning with `"AKM_CC_Test_"` and ending in a sequence of `1:nrow(pipel)` with leading zeros.

```
x <- "AKM_CC_Test_"
sprintf("%s%0*d", x, 30 - nchar(x), 1:nrow(pipel))
```

- `%s` inserts `x` into the string
- `%0*d` adds `1:nrow(pipel)` with `*` leading zeros, after `x`. The `*` is used to insert `30 - nchar(x)` into the format (I did it programatically; you could just insert 18 there if you want)

An example on a simple length 5 (`1:5`) vector would be

```
x <- "AKM_CC_Test_"
sprintf("%s%0*d", x, 30 - nchar(x), 1:5)
# [1] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000001" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000002"
# [3] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000003" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000004"
# [5] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000005"
```

Comment: Thanks the code above worked and created the IDs I was looking for but when I tried to write the new table using  write.table(pipel, "pipel9.txt", sep=" ",quote = FALSE, col.names=TRUE) the ID column didn't show in the table.

Comment: @Curious - what code did you use  to add the column?

Comment: @ Rich Scriven- I tried to use: 
newtable<- cbind(id=X, pipel)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:` or `seq` for sequences and you can prepend your leading text with `paste` or `paste0`. The heart of the question is on the number padding with leading 0's.

Your options are:

1. `stri_pad` from `stringi` (more intuitive)
2. `str_pad` from `stringr` (more intuitive)
3. `sprintf` (no packages needed)
4. `formatC` (good if you're familiar with C's `printf`)

Note that some cases, though not this particular one, necessitate disabling scientific notation for numbers in the sequence. This can be done with `options` or `with_options` from `devtools`.

Please see [this popular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r) for examples of each.

Using `formatC`:

```
uid <- paste0("AKM_CC_Test_", formatC(1:10000, width = 18, format = "d", flag = "0"))
head(uid)
```

> ```
> [1] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000001" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000002" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000003" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000004"
> [5] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000005" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000006"
> ```

Using the `stringr` package:

```
uid <- paste0("AKM_CC_Test_", str_pad(1:10000, 18, pad = "0")) # remember to load stringr
head(uid)
```

> ```
> [1] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000001" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000002" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000003" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000004"
> [5] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000005" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000006"
> ```

Using `sprintf`:

```
head(sprintf("%s%0*d", "AKM_CC_Test_", 18,  1:10000))
```

> ```
> [1] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000001" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000002" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000003" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000004"
> [5] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000005" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000006"
> ```

Using `stri_pad` from the package `stringi`:

```
uid <- paste0("AKM_CC_Test_", stri_pad(1:10000, 18, pad = "0")) # remember to load stringi
head(uid)
```

> ```
> [1] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000001" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000002" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000003" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000004"
> [5] "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000005" "AKM_CC_Test_000000000000000006"
> ```

Comment: Why did you add my answer to yours?

Comment: @RichScriven What are you talking about? I using the list of padding options on the linked post and I did it differently and comparing/contrasting them. It's just a function Rich, it's not your answer.

Comment: Oh get real.  It's the same thing.

Comment: @RichScriven Wow. All I can say is wow. I answer ahead of you, link a source with a list of options, and apply all of them one by one and you're going to whine and downvote because an option you used is on the famous list? Are there any others I should know are off limits? Can I still use `<-` and `paste`?