# Padding and Reducing Characters

Tags: r, padding

I am very new to R. I have a numeric vector, let's say `data <- c(1,3, 5, 10, 101)`. What I need is to have every element as a character, add a zero to single digits, and not have more than two characters in every element.  I am using the following code:

```
pad <- str_pad(data, width = 2, side = "left", pad="0")
```

But this still does not reduce "101" to "10". Any suggestions?

This is different from an earlier thread on padding which does not provide me an answer to how to reduce "101" to "10"

Comment: `str_pad` is not a base R function. Please include the names of the relevant packages that you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding leading zeros using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r)

Comment: I referred to "Adding leading zeros using R ". But I couldn't find the answer to reducing 3 digit characters to two digits. The code I have written is from that thread itself.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this, but wrap the result in `substr`: `substr(str_pad(data, width = 2, side = "left", pad="0"), 1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that would do what you want

```
str_pad = function(data){    
     data = ifelse(abs(data)<10,
                         paste("0", data,sep = ""),
                         ifelse(abs(data)>100,
                                substr(as.character(data),1,2),
                                as.character(data))) 
    return(data)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)

data <- c(1,3, 5, 10, 101)
data <- as.character(data)
data <- strtrim(data, 2)
data <- str_pad(data, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0")
data
# [1] "01" "03" "05" "10" "10"
```

I split up the steps but you could easily nest some of those steps as well.

Comment: Thanks Craig. That does it!