# Replace single or multiple spaces with single/multiple zeros

Tags: r

Ultimately I want to convert this value into `as.numeric` but before this I want to replace space for zeros. I do 2 step `sub` here as I can do only single space at the time. Can do this in one command?

```
x <- c('  3','1 2','12 ')    ## could be leading, trailing or in the mid
x
as.numeric(x)      ## <@><<    NAs introduced by coercion
x <- sub(' ','0',sub(' ','0',x))
as.numeric(x)
```

Comment: What is the point of adding leading zeroes to a whole number?

Comment: What's wrong with just `as.numeric(x)`? (FYI `sub('\\s+', '00', x)`)

Comment: yes, just do as.numeric(x), to remove all spaces do `gsub('\\s', '', x)`. What Sotos gave will replace with zeroes the first sequence of zeros that is encountered (it won't for example replace spaces that would be after the first non empty characters if x <- '  3  '

Comment: Use formatting options (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r)):
`x <- 25499`

`sprintf("%06d", x)`

`[1] "025499"`

Comment: Thanks guys all, I don't want to break alignment as it's pretty complex structure, it's logical 0,1,2,3s and I refer to my value by substring(x,120,122),  + I need to keep it for audit. So Ideally I would like just to replace blanks with zeros. I modified my sample to be more real, so as.numeric will break on it. For other calcs it will work as suggested by all you . Tx M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can replace all leading white space to leading 0.

```
# Load package
library(stringr)

# Create example strings with leading white space and number
x <- c("  3", "    4", "    12")

x %>%
  # Trim the leading white space
  str_trim(side = "left") %>%
  # Add leading 0, the length is based on the original stringlength
  str_pad(width = str_length(x), side = "left", pad = "0")

#[1] "003"    "00004"  "000012"
```

#### Update

My previous attempt is actually convoluted. Using `gsub` can achieve the same thing with only one line.

```
gsub(" ", "0", x)
#[1] "003"    "00004"  "000012"
```

And it does not have to be leading white space. Taking the update from the OP as an example.

```
x <- c('  3','1 2','12 ')
gsub(" ", "0", x)
#[1] "003" "102" "120"
```