# How to prevent R from dropping leading zeros in an integer vector

Tags: r

Is there any way of stopping R from dropping leading zeros in an integer? e.g.,

a<-c(00217,00007,00017)

I understand this is not the correct way of writing integers. Sadly I've been given a text file (person and non-R code are not around anymore) containing thousands of vectors in a single list:
list(drugA=c(...), drugB=c(....),........)

I need to keep the leading zeros as 00002 becomes 2. I could load these thousands of values in and then write a function to parse the list and convert into characters whilst correcting for any number that isn't five characters long but I was hoping for a speedy alternative.

**UPDATE1**
An example of the text file I've been provided:

```
list(CETUXIMAB=c(05142,05316),
DORNASEALFA=c(94074),
ETANERCEPT=c(05342,99075),
BIVALIRUDIN=c(04400,09177),
LEUPROLIDE=c(02074,03219,91035,91086),
PEGINTERFERONALFA2A=c(03162),
ALTEPLASE=c(00486,01032,03371,05314),
DARBEPOETINALFA=c(02217,03421),
GOSERELIN=c(99221),
RETEPLASE=c(00157),
ERYTHROPOIETIN=c(92078,92122))
```

I have truncated the list as there are thousands of vectors. This was a text file generated using a program written in C++ (code not available). Some of the values e.g., RETEPLASE=c(00157) becomes truncated to 157.

Comment: Anthony, can you provide an example of the data you are working with. Separately, my sense is to recommend you review the following question and answer and linked answers. I hope this points you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/5812493?lq=1

I hope the above helps.

Comment: That data is not numeric data. Import it as characters.

Comment: Thanks for those links, Technophobe01. I've added a larger real example.

Comment: Also, `sprintf("%05d", 2)`.

Comment: Use text processing to add quotes around the numbers before you source the file. Obviously, the person who created this file had no clue what they were doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(a, 5, pad = "0")
```