# Convert number to character in R, keeping leading zero, and not performing calcs

Tags: r

I want this `c(002, 005/010)` to become `c("002", "005/010")`.

`as.character(c(002, 005/010))` doesn't work, as it returns `c("2", "0.5")`

So I need to keep any leading zeros (including the `005` and `010` in the example), and I want to convert to character without first performing that calculation (perhaps I can first sub the `/` with ws...)

The actual values are from much longer text files of csvs, e.g.

```
047126002/047126003/047126004/047126005, 047016064, 047033008,
047265002, 047325004, 047265004, 047265003, 047033010,
047082004/047082005, 047058002, 047016030, 047320007, 047313005, ...
```

Comment: Your only chance to change `005/010` to something other than `0.5` is at the time of input. You can add leading 0s with `sprintf` or `formatC`, [as in this R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812493/903061). But the denominator you used to make `0.5`, whether its `1/2`, `5/10`, or `005/010`, is not preserved. If these are inputs to a function you can grab them before they're evaluated... please edit your question if that is the case.

Comment: The vectors are the output of another program, and can be very long. They are actually area identifiers, so carry no numeric info. If I read them is as numbers, the x/x calculations happen; if I read them in as character, the calc still happens, and the zeros are lost.

Comment: "output of another program" is it a text file?

Comment: Yes, it can be a text file.

Comment: Can you add example text file to your post?

Comment: Try: `df1 <- read.table("myFile.txt", sep = ",", fill = TRUE, colClasses = rep("character", 6))`

Comment: Or read.csv("myFile.csv", header = F, colClasses = rep("character", <numOfColumns>))

Comment: Those approaches work. Thanks.