# how can I paste specific names with paste

Tags: r

I cannot figure out how to do this in one run

G07, G08, G09, G11, G12, G13, G14

so I know how to do the first one

```
paste0("G0",7:9)
```

i also know how to do the second part

```
paste0("G",10:14)
```

All what I could think of is to combine them by rbind

```
rbind (paste0("G0",7:9),paste0("G",10:14))
```

this is not a good way and I am looking to see if you can guide me to find a better way?

Comment: replace `rbind` with `c`...? Not quite sure I follow, to be honest.

Comment: @joran I just want to paste the G07, G08, G09, G11, G12, G13, G14 in one command , this is all what I am trying to do :-p

Comment: try: `paste0("G", c(7:9, 10:14))`

Comment: @missuse it does not print the 0 before 07, 08 etc that is the problem :-p

Comment: @Nik Bernou I understand, did not think of that, Vlo has your back tho.

Comment: @missuse thank I'll accept his answer in 4 minutes :-)

Comment: For other approaches see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `sprintf()` instead

```
sprintf("G%02d", c(7:9, 10:14))

[1] "G07" "G08" "G09" "G10" "G11" "G12" "G13" "G14"
```

Comment: You could just use 7:14 with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `stringr::str_pad` for this

```
paste0("G", stringr::str_pad(7:14, 2, side="left", pad="0"))
# "G07" "G08" "G09" "G10" "G11" "G12" "G13" "G14"
```