# Re-creating a bar-code/ID variable from a number of columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have some data on products with a unique code. I am trying to re-create this code from information in other columns.

The data I have looks like the following;

```
   UPC               SY    GE    VEND  ITEM 
   <chr>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 00-01-85674-60002 0     1     85674 60002
 2 00-01-85674-60001 0     1     85674 60001
 3 00-01-85674-60004 0     1     85674 60004
 4 27-01-15502-01124 27    1     15502 1124 
 5 00-01-80020-00001 0     1     80020 1    
 6 00-01-80020-24221 0     1     80020 24221
 7 00-01-80020-31799 0     1     80020 31799
 8 00-01-80020-00004 0     1     80020 4    
 9 00-01-80020-35333 0     1     80020 35333
10 00-01-80020-00002 0     1     80020 2
```

I am trying to re-create the `UPC` column from the `SY`, `GE`, `VEND`and `ITEM` columns.

The first one is somewhat straight forward.

Add a 0 to the beginning of the `SY` column, another 0 to the `GE` column and add in `VEND` and `ITEM` - then add dashes inbetween each column.

However I am having problems with rows similar to row 4. If I follow the method previously I would obtain.

`027-001-15502-01124` which would not match up to the other products.

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to how I can go about replicating the same structure as the `UPC` column from the other 4 columns?

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(UPC = c("00-01-85674-60002", "00-01-85674-60001", 
"00-01-85674-60004", "27-01-15502-01124", "00-01-80020-00001", 
"00-01-80020-24221", "00-01-80020-31799", "00-01-80020-00004", 
"00-01-80020-35333", "00-01-80020-00002", "00-01-80020-24220", 
"00-01-80020-10001", "27-01-15502-01125", "00-01-80020-00005", 
"27-02-15504-05184", "00-01-80022-42230", "27-01-15502-01126", 
"00-01-80020-00003", "00-01-80020-35332", "06-01-07634-00011", 
"06-01-07634-00021", "27-01-00007-10404", "00-02-40850-00000", 
"00-01-40850-02001", "00-01-40850-03001", "00-01-40850-06001", 
"00-01-40850-00005", "00-01-40850-02005", "00-01-40850-00004", 
"00-01-40850-02004", "00-01-40850-00001", "00-01-40850-02002", 
"00-01-40850-03002", "00-01-40850-03006", "00-01-40850-02006", 
"00-01-40850-00006", "00-01-40850-06010", "00-01-40850-07010", 
"00-02-40850-03010", "00-01-40850-00003", "06-01-03675-10295", 
"27-01-15503-00343", "27-01-15504-00629", "06-01-03675-10287", 
"06-01-03675-10286", "27-01-15503-02068", "06-01-03675-10383", 
"06-01-03675-10595", "06-02-03675-10187", "27-01-15503-00708", 
"27-01-15504-00630", "06-01-03675-10195", "06-01-03675-10186", 
"27-01-15503-03729", "07-01-66895-86000", "27-01-15504-02609", 
"00-02-72783-00059", "27-01-15503-03887", "00-03-72783-00050", 
"00-02-72783-00009", "00-02-72783-00300", "27-01-15502-01130", 
"27-01-15503-01162", "27-01-15504-00631", "00-01-72783-00007", 
"27-01-15503-03666", "00-01-72783-00033", "00-01-72783-00400", 
"00-01-72783-00004", "00-01-72783-00200", "27-01-15502-01133", 
"27-01-15503-01161", "27-01-15504-00633", "00-01-72783-00006", 
"00-01-72783-00022", "00-01-72783-12100", "00-01-72783-01000", 
"00-01-07278-30010", "00-01-72783-00100", "00-01-72783-00600", 
"27-01-15503-00046", "27-01-15504-00632", "00-01-72783-00005", 
"00-01-72783-00011", "00-01-72783-00066", "00-01-09125-00016", 
"00-01-09125-00005", "27-01-15503-03375", "00-02-09125-00010", 
"00-01-09125-00040", "00-01-09125-00146", "00-01-09125-00006", 
"27-01-15503-03376", "00-02-09125-00030", "00-01-09125-00076", 
"00-01-09125-00070", "00-02-09125-00020", "00-01-09125-00066", 
"27-01-15503-03738", "00-01-09125-00007"), SY = c("0", "0", "0", 
"27", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "27", "0", "27", 
"0", "27", "0", "0", "6", "6", "27", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"6", "27", "27", "6", "6", "27", "6", "6", "6", "27", "27", "6", 
"6", "27", "7", "27", "0", "27", "0", "0", "0", "27", "27", "27", 
"0", "27", "0", "0", "0", "0", "27", "27", "27", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "27", "27", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "27", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "27", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "27", "0"), 
    GE = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
    "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
    "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1"), VEND = c("85674", "85674", 
    "85674", "15502", "80020", "80020", "80020", "80020", "80020", 
    "80020", "80020", "80020", "15502", "80020", "15504", "80022", 
    "15502", "80020", "80020", "7634", "7634", "7", "40850", 
    "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", 
    "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", "40850", 
    "40850", "40850", "40850", "3675", "15503", "15504", "3675", 
    "3675", "15503", "3675", "3675", "3675", "15503", "15504", 
    "3675", "3675", "15503", "66895", "15504", "72783", "15503", 
    "72783", "72783", "72783", "15502", "15503", "15504", "72783", 
    "15503", "72783", "72783", "72783", "72783", "15502", "15503", 
    "15504", "72783", "72783", "72783", "72783", "7278", "72783", 
    "72783", "15503", "15504", "72783", "72783", "72783", "9125", 
    "9125", "15503", "9125", "9125", "9125", "9125", "15503", 
    "9125", "9125", "9125", "9125", "9125", "15503", "9125"), 
    ITEM = c("60002", "60001", "60004", "1124", "1", "24221", 
    "31799", "4", "35333", "2", "24220", "10001", "1125", "5", 
    "5184", "42230", "1126", "3", "35332", "11", "21", "10404", 
    "0", "2001", "3001", "6001", "5", "2005", "4", "2004", "1", 
    "2002", "3002", "3006", "2006", "6", "6010", "7010", "3010", 
    "3", "10295", "343", "629", "10287", "10286", "2068", "10383", 
    "10595", "10187", "708", "630", "10195", "10186", "3729", 
    "86000", "2609", "59", "3887", "50", "9", "300", "1130", 
    "1162", "631", "7", "3666", "33", "400", "4", "200", "1133", 
    "1161", "633", "6", "22", "12100", "1000", "30010", "100", 
    "600", "46", "632", "5", "11", "66", "16", "5", "3375", "10", 
    "40", "146", "6", "3376", "30", "76", "70", "20", "66", "3738", 
    "7")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I'd start with `mutate`ing your non-UPC columns using `sprintf` or `str_pad` so that they're the right format ([link to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r)).  After that, you can use `paste` within a `mutate` to combine them into your UPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `stringr` (part of the `tidyverse`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(UPC2 = str_c(str_pad(SY, width = 2, pad = "0"),
                      str_pad(GE, width = 2, pad = "0"),
                      str_pad(VEND, width = 5, pad = "0"),
                      str_pad(ITEM, width = 5, pad = "0"), sep = "-"))
df2
# # A tibble: 100 x 6
#    UPC               SY    GE    VEND  ITEM  UPC2             
#    <chr>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>            
#  1 00-01-85674-60002 0     1     85674 60002 00-01-85674-60002
#  2 00-01-85674-60001 0     1     85674 60001 00-01-85674-60001
#  3 00-01-85674-60004 0     1     85674 60004 00-01-85674-60004
#  4 27-01-15502-01124 27    1     15502 1124  27-01-15502-01124
#  5 00-01-80020-00001 0     1     80020 1     00-01-80020-00001
#  6 00-01-80020-24221 0     1     80020 24221 00-01-80020-24221
#  7 00-01-80020-31799 0     1     80020 31799 00-01-80020-31799
#  8 00-01-80020-00004 0     1     80020 4     00-01-80020-00004
#  9 00-01-80020-35333 0     1     80020 35333 00-01-80020-35333
# 10 00-01-80020-00002 0     1     80020 2     00-01-80020-00002
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: This works great, thank you very much. One question so I understand the code. The `pad = "0"` tells R to "pad" out the column of fixed width 2 (or 5) with `0`? So it will have a fixed width of 2, with 1 value already occupaying the space and fill in the remaining empty values with a `0`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option with `sprintf`.  Convert the columns other than the first one to `numeric`, and use `sprintf` with the `fmt` specified to pad 0s at the beginning

```
do.call(sprintf, c(lapply(df[-1], as.numeric), fmt = "%02d-%02d-%05d-%05d"))
```