# Include leading zero when using Rank function in R

Tags: r, sorting, rank, zero

```
testdf = data.frame(name=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o"), score = c(11,15,46,32,22,68,89,35,54,12,44,3,1,88,6))
testdf$rank<-rank(testdf$score)
```

when using the rank function in R it doesnt include leading zeros-- it ranks

```
1 
2
3
...
10
11
12
```

but that means sometimes when it sorts it sorts as: 1, 10, 11, 12...2, 21, 22, 23...3, 31, 32, 33. instead of 1, 2, 3, 4.

is there a way to include the leading zero with the rank function such that the output is 01, 02, 03, 04, etc

the complete example that i am using is not reproducible on here. i am using the rank function then combining it with another column to create a rank and total (converts to character). See this image of the output

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8PzC.jpg]

you will see that it is ordering by 1, 10, 11...2, 20, 21, etc. rather than 1,2,3,4...which is why i was hoping to include leading zeros because when i combine the columns it is no longer a numeric vector

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]? `rank` should return `"A numeric vector"` which you can sort in R using proper numeric sorting. How are you trying to sort this? Are you converting the output of `rank` into `character` and then trying to sort? Please show us a complete example of what you're doing, what is happening, and what you want to happen.

Comment: adding now...the data is included

Comment: when I sort on the `score` column I get an ascending `rank` column. Could you provide your output and why it doesn't match your expectations?

Comment: It will sort it as `1, 10, 11, 12...` only when they are characters. If they are kept as numeric it would sort it as expected.

Comment: yes i understand that it will order like that, which is why i was asking if there is a way within the function to include leading zeros. the complete example that i am using is no reproducible on here. i am using the rank function then combining it with another column to create a rank and total. See this image of the output https://imgur.com/a/jKfIFWs you will see that it is ordering by 1, 10, 11...2, 20, 21, etc. rather than 1,2,3,4...which is why i was hoping to include leading zeros because when i combine the columns it is no longer a numeric vector

Comment: There is also `gtools::mixedorder` and `gtools::mixedsort` which might help you in this case.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but this doesnt answer the question. I saw you marked this as duplicate but it isnt a duplicate...I am asking if there is the ability within the Rank function to include leading zeros (e.g., add_zero = TRUE, or something similar)

Comment: If you read `?rank` there is no such provision in the `rank` function. To get your expected output you need to hack around with `sprintf` or similar other functions as shown in the duplicate. (You also have got similar answers here). Hence, I marked it as duplicate of that question.

Comment: I did read ?rank and that was why I was asking about it...because I didn't see it in there. I have run into help files with missing data, or I could miss it myself even if it's staring me in the face sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is pad the string with leading 0's. It's important to pad, rather than just add a 0 with `paste` or `sprintf`, because while `02` will come before `10`, it won't come before `010`.
The below options will work with any vector and are not `rank` specific. This question (probably a duplicate) shows many options: [How to add leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros)

Here's the easiest way:

```
testdf$rank
  [1]  4  6 11  8  7 13 15  9 12  5 10  2  1 14  3

stringr::str_pad(testdf$rank, width = 3, side = 'left', pad = '0')

 [1] "004" "006" "011" "008" "007" "013" "015" "009" "012" "005" "010" "002"
[13] "001" "014" "003"
```

The `width` argument tells how long you want these strings to be, and the `pad` argument will be added to the `side` side of the string until they're all the same length

Comment: i appreciate that...i know how to add the leading zeros with stringr, but i was wondering if there is an ability to do it within the rank function (e.g., add_zero = TRUE, or something similar)

Comment: No, since rank returns a numeric vector and there is no concept of leading zeros in  a `numeric`. It's only a thing you can or might want to do if you're converting from numeric to character

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace 2 in %02d with the number of digits that should be there for any rank):

```
testdf$rank <- sprintf("%02d",rank(testdf$score))
```