# Why is formatC() function introducing NA by coercion on some specific values?

Tags: r, number-formatting

I'm trying to format numbers so they have a fixed width introducing leading zeros were needed. Following this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816779/8218904) to a related question I'm using the [`formatC`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/formatC) function to achieve this. But I am getting unexpected results.

For instance, this code works as expected:

```
formatC(2102040015, format = "d", width = 10, flag = "0")
## [1] "2102040015"
```

```
formatC(102040015, format = "d", width = 10, flag = "0")
## [1] "0102040015"
```

But when I try to use the very same approach with these numbers I get the strange result:

```
formatC(2152040015, format = "d", width = 10, flag = "0")
## Warning message:
## In storage.mode(x) <- "integer" :
##  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
## [1] "        NA"
```

```
formatC(2522040015, format = "d", width = 10, flag = "0")
## Warning message:
## In storage.mode(x) <- "integer" :
##  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
## [1] "        NA"
```

After some testing, I have come to the conclusion that for every number greater than `2150000000` I get this message and the `"        NA"` result. I would appreciate if you gave me insights about this behavior. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you use `format="d"` you are telling R that you will be formatting integers specifically. The largest integer R can store is `.Machine$integer.max` which usually is

```
.Machine$integer.max
# [1] 2147483647
```

Numbers over that amount are stored as floating point numbers. So perhaps you would like to use this instead:

```
formatC(2152040015, format = "f", width = 10, flag = "0", digits = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick this totally answers my question! So I guess `format = "f"` (combined with the `digits = 0` argument) is a more general approach, right? Think I would use it from now on.