# how to create a 4 digit numeric list in r for codification purposes

Tags: r

I want to create a list of 4 digits of numbers ranging from 0 to 9999 as per the ezample bellow:

```
list(c("0001","0002","0003","...","9998","9999"))
```

Comment: `sprintf("%04d", 1:9999)`

Comment: See: [How to add leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812493/10488504)

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatC,

```
formatC(1:999, width=4, flag = "0")
```

or `sprintf("%04d", 1:9999)` mentioned by GKi