# Using dplyr to replace negative values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable with numeric integers -6 to 3450. I want to replace anything <0 with its absolute value and 00 in front.

So for example

```
-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0
```

Become

```
006, 005, 004, 003, 002, 001, 000
```

And all the other integers stay the same.

I think there must be a way to do this with ‘replace’.. my best guess..

```
data <- replace(data$var1, data$var1 < 1, ‘00 + abs()’)
```

Comment: Is it ok, if your column is chr datatype?

Comment: Very likely a duplicate of [How to add leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros) unless there is some further complication. E.g.: `replace(x, x <= 0, sprintf("%03d", abs(x))[x <= 0] )`

Comment: @thelatemail agreed, this looks like a duplicate of what you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
v <- -6:3450

ifelse(v <= 0, formatC(abs(v), width = 3, flag = "0"), v)

   [1] "006" "005" "004" "003" "002" "001" "000"   "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"  
  [16] "9"   "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23"
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

In TidyR:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- tibble(x=c(-6, -5 , 100, 101), y=rnorm(4))
df %>% mutate(x = ifelse(x < 0, str_pad(abs(x), pad = "0", width = 3), x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Data

```
s <- data.frame(var1=-6:3400)
```

Looks like

```
> head(s)
  var1
1   -6
2   -5
3   -4
4   -3
5   -2
6   -1
```

Create requested `var2`

```
library(dplyr)
ss <- mutate(s, var2 = ifelse(var1<0, as.character(sprintf("%03d", var1*-1)), var1)) 

> head(ss)
  var1 var2
1   -6  006
2   -5  005
3   -4  004
4   -3  003
5   -2  002
6   -1  001
```

Comment: should be `"%03d"` instead of `"%03s"`.  Corrected please