# Is there a way in R to select column names if they have consistent naming convention?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table one using the [TableOne package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tableone) where I have specify my variables that will be stratified. Is there a way in R to specify a list of columns if they have standardized naming convention. I.e my columns go c01, c02 all the way to c64? i.e. can i do something like vars="c01-c64" in the Table One package.

Comment: Related possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812493/680068

Comment: TableOne has "vars" argument, use above post to create zero prefixed vector.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. For you example you can filter with "c %in% vars" to get the colnames with "c" in them. Check out the {stringr} and {stringi} packages for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
list <-df[,grep("c", colnames(df))] %>% colnames()
```

Comment: If you're using `%>%`, you're probably using `dplyr`, so `df %>% select(starts_with("c"))` might be nicer.

Comment: If you just need the column names `grep("c", colnames(df), value = TRUE)` should give you that.