# Adding leading zeros to adjust the number to the right format

Tags: r, zero, leading-zero

I have a column in a data frame in R that looks like this:

10.01  10.04  10.08  9.99  9.95  9.98  9.1

I need all of the numbers to have the same number of digits by adding zeros to the beginning or the end but only if there are less than 5 characters (two numbers in each side of the decimal point):

10.01  10.04  10.08  09.99  09.95  09.98  09.10

how can I do it in R?
thank you

Comment: sorry, I edited the question
I'm using R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sprintf()`. Based on the documentation, in the pattern `"%05.2f"`, `%` is the start of the specification; `0` means padding with leading zero; `5` is the total length of the output including the decimal; `2` means the decimal number allowed; `f` means it is a decimal number. The output is a character vector.

```
x <- c(10.01, 10.04, 10.08, 9.99, 9.95, 9.98, 9.1)
sprintf("%05.2f", x)

# [1] "10.01" "10.04" "10.08" "09.99" "09.95" "09.98" "09.10"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I tried it but got this message error:
Error in sprintf("%05.2f", Formula$Lat) : 
  invalid format '%05.2f'; use format %s for character objects

Comment: Is `Formula$Lat` a character? If so, perhaps you can convert it to numeric before using `sprintf()`. Something like `sprintf("%05.2f", as.numeric(Formula$Lat))`.

Comment: your values are probably saved as characters and not as numeric or integer. `as.numeric(variable_values)` should fix it