# unable to extract date, month and year in three separate columns from dataframe's "Date" column in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" or "dd/m/yyyy"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I was trying to use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# Dataframe has "Date" column and date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" or "dd/m/yyyy"
df <- data.frame(Date = c("10/1/2001", "15/01/2010", "15/2/2010", "20/02/2010", "25/3/2010", "31/03/2010"))

# extract into three columns
df %>% extract(Date, c("Day", "Month", "Year"), "([^/]+), ([^/]+), ([^)]+)")
```

But above code is returning:

```
   Day Month Year
1 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
2 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
3 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
4 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
5 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
6 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

How to correctly extract the dates in the result as expected:

```
   Day Month Year
1 10  1 2010
2 15  1 2010
3 15  2 2010
4 20  2 2010
5 25  3 2010
6 31  3 2010
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be easier to use `separate` in this case

```
df %>% 
  separate("Date", into=c("Day","Month","Year"), sep="/") %>% 
  mutate(Month=str_replace(Month, "^0",""))
```

That will keep everything as character values. If you want the values to be numeric, use

```
df %>% 
  separate("Date", into=c("Day","Month","Year"), sep="/", convert=TRUE)
```

Comment: just one question, if i wanted to keep month and date in the formats such as 01, 02, 03.... 11, 12, .... 30, 31 , is it possible in here?

Comment: Use the first option and skip the `mutate()` step. That's just there to remove the leading zero. If you want to add missing zeros, then you can use one of the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros

Comment: Agree. but that will keep the format for month as "1" from the date 15/1/2010, instead "01" isn't it? but actually i was thinking to have "01", instead "1".  Looking for a workaround method :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex pattern is off.  Use this version:

```r
df %>% extract(Date, c("Day", "Month", "Year"), "(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Date = dmy(Date), # if your Date column is character type
           across(Date, funs(year, month, day)))
```

```
        Date Date_year Date_month Date_day
1 2001-01-10      2001          1       10
2 2010-01-15      2010          1       15
3 2010-02-15      2010          2       15
4 2010-02-20      2010          2       20
5 2010-03-25      2010          3       25
6 2010-03-31      2010          3       31
```

Comment: Thanks :) - just one question, if I wanted to keep month and date in the formats such as 01, 02, 03.... 11, 12, .... 30, 31 , is it possible in this code? or will require some other tweaking?

Comment: You could add `mutate(Date_month_char = sprintf("%02d", Date_month))`. This will give you a character column. Or if you want the month names abbreviated: `mutate(Date_month_abbr = month(Date_month, label = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

We may use `read.table` from `base R`

```
read.table(text = df$Date, sep="/", header = FALSE, 
     col.names = c("Day", "Month", "Year"))
  Day Month Year
1  10     1 2001
2  15     1 2010
3  15     2 2010
4  20     2 2010
5  25     3 2010
6  31     3 2010
```