# How to update number into time format in R for numeric smaller than 0

Tags: date, parsing, time, lubridate

I have this original dataset of time series, where V2 is the date (class: integer) and V3 is the timestamp but it is written now in number starting from 0 to 2355 (every 5-min frequency) in which 0 means 00:00, 5 means 00:05, ..., 55 means 00:55, 100  means 01:00, 105 means 01:05 and so on. The format of column V3 (time) as follows:

```
> head(data0$V3, 20)
[1]   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55 100 105 110 115 120 125
[19] 130 135
```

I want to combine my date and time columns into one column called 'datetime'. I tried these codes below for this purpose.

```
data0$V3 <- sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", data0$V3) # put in delimitter
```

The result:

```
> head(data0$V3, 20)
 [1] "0"    "5"    "10"   "15"   "20"   "25"   "30"   "35"   "40"   "45" 
[11] "50"   "55"   "1:00" "1:05" "1:10" "1:15" "1:20" "1:25" "1:30" "1:35"
```

Then

```
library(lubridate)
data0$datetime = ymd_hm(paste(data0$V2, data0$V3))
```

The results:

```
> head(data0$datetime, 20)
[1] NA                        NA
[3] NA                        NA
...
[11] NA                        NA
[13] "2015-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:05:00 UTC"
[15] "2015-01-01 01:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:15:00 UTC"
...
[19] "2015-01-01 01:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:35:00 UTC"
```

From this result, they seem to work OK for the time from 100 to 2355 but fails to parse for time from 0 to 55. My guess is that these numbers are not understood as time format like the others from the beginning.

Can anyone help to solve the problem with the timestamp from 0 to 55 in this case so that I have the same result throughout the dataset? My idea is maybe to convert the [0;55] into format like [00;055] before applying the first code line but is it possible because as number, 0 is always omitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are no leading zeros in the first numbers. You can add leading zeros with answers from this question: [How to add leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros). I chose `formatC()` because it allows to format the output to a fixed width. In case of Hour:Minute format, desirable width is 4 digits: Like `00:00` or `22:45`.

I expanded your example data until `10:55` so we can have some cases with two-digit-hours.

Below is the code:

```r
times <- vector(mode = "integer", length = 0)
for (i in (0:10)*100) {
  times <- c(times, 
             seq(from = i,
               to = i + 55,
               by = 5))
}
times
#>   [1]    0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55  100  105  110
#>  [16]  115  120  125  130  135  140  145  150  155  200  205  210  215  220  225
#>  [31]  230  235  240  245  250  255  300  305  310  315  320  325  330  335  340
#>  [46]  345  350  355  400  405  410  415  420  425  430  435  440  445  450  455
#>  [61]  500  505  510  515  520  525  530  535  540  545  550  555  600  605  610
#>  [76]  615  620  625  630  635  640  645  650  655  700  705  710  715  720  725
#>  [91]  730  735  740  745  750  755  800  805  810  815  820  825  830  835  840
#> [106]  845  850  855  900  905  910  915  920  925  930  935  940  945  950  955
#> [121] 1000 1005 1010 1015 1020 1025 1030 1035 1040 1045 1050 1055

# add leading zeros so that total width is always 4
(times <- formatC(times, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"))
#>   [1] "0000" "0005" "0010" "0015" "0020" "0025" "0030" "0035" "0040" "0045"
#>  [11] "0050" "0055" "0100" "0105" "0110" "0115" "0120" "0125" "0130" "0135"
#>  [21] "0140" "0145" "0150" "0155" "0200" "0205" "0210" "0215" "0220" "0225"
#>  [31] "0230" "0235" "0240" "0245" "0250" "0255" "0300" "0305" "0310" "0315"
#>  [41] "0320" "0325" "0330" "0335" "0340" "0345" "0350" "0355" "0400" "0405"
#>  [51] "0410" "0415" "0420" "0425" "0430" "0435" "0440" "0445" "0450" "0455"
#>  [61] "0500" "0505" "0510" "0515" "0520" "0525" "0530" "0535" "0540" "0545"
#>  [71] "0550" "0555" "0600" "0605" "0610" "0615" "0620" "0625" "0630" "0635"
#>  [81] "0640" "0645" "0650" "0655" "0700" "0705" "0710" "0715" "0720" "0725"
#>  [91] "0730" "0735" "0740" "0745" "0750" "0755" "0800" "0805" "0810" "0815"
#> [101] "0820" "0825" "0830" "0835" "0840" "0845" "0850" "0855" "0900" "0905"
#> [111] "0910" "0915" "0920" "0925" "0930" "0935" "0940" "0945" "0950" "0955"
#> [121] "1000" "1005" "1010" "1015" "1020" "1025" "1030" "1035" "1040" "1045"
#> [131] "1050" "1055"

# add divider : 
times <- sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", times)

lubridate::ymd_hm(paste("2015-01-01", times))
#>   [1] "2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:05:00 UTC"
#>   [3] "2015-01-01 00:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:15:00 UTC"
#>   [5] "2015-01-01 00:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:25:00 UTC"
#>   [7] "2015-01-01 00:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:35:00 UTC"
#>   [9] "2015-01-01 00:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:45:00 UTC"
#>  [11] "2015-01-01 00:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:55:00 UTC"
#>  [13] "2015-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:05:00 UTC"
#>  [15] "2015-01-01 01:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:15:00 UTC"
#>  [17] "2015-01-01 01:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:25:00 UTC"
#>  [19] "2015-01-01 01:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:35:00 UTC"
#>  [21] "2015-01-01 01:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:45:00 UTC"
#>  [23] "2015-01-01 01:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:55:00 UTC"
#>  [25] "2015-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:05:00 UTC"
#>  [27] "2015-01-01 02:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:15:00 UTC"
#>  [29] "2015-01-01 02:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:25:00 UTC"
#>  [31] "2015-01-01 02:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:35:00 UTC"
#>  [33] "2015-01-01 02:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:45:00 UTC"
#>  [35] "2015-01-01 02:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:55:00 UTC"
#>  [37] "2015-01-01 03:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 03:05:00 UTC"
#>  [39] "2015-01-01 03:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 03:15:00 UTC"
#>  [41] "2015-01-01 03:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 03:25:00 UTC"
#>  [43] "2015-01-01 03:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 03:35:00 UTC"
#>  [45] "2015-01-01 03:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 03:45:00 UTC"
#>  [47] "2015-01-01 03:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 03:55:00 UTC"
#>  [49] "2015-01-01 04:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 04:05:00 UTC"
#>  [51] "2015-01-01 04:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 04:15:00 UTC"
#>  [53] "2015-01-01 04:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 04:25:00 UTC"
#>  [55] "2015-01-01 04:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 04:35:00 UTC"
#>  [57] "2015-01-01 04:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 04:45:00 UTC"
#>  [59] "2015-01-01 04:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 04:55:00 UTC"
#>  [61] "2015-01-01 05:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 05:05:00 UTC"
#>  [63] "2015-01-01 05:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 05:15:00 UTC"
#>  [65] "2015-01-01 05:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 05:25:00 UTC"
#>  [67] "2015-01-01 05:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 05:35:00 UTC"
#>  [69] "2015-01-01 05:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 05:45:00 UTC"
#>  [71] "2015-01-01 05:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 05:55:00 UTC"
#>  [73] "2015-01-01 06:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 06:05:00 UTC"
#>  [75] "2015-01-01 06:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 06:15:00 UTC"
#>  [77] "2015-01-01 06:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 06:25:00 UTC"
#>  [79] "2015-01-01 06:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 06:35:00 UTC"
#>  [81] "2015-01-01 06:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 06:45:00 UTC"
#>  [83] "2015-01-01 06:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 06:55:00 UTC"
#>  [85] "2015-01-01 07:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 07:05:00 UTC"
#>  [87] "2015-01-01 07:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 07:15:00 UTC"
#>  [89] "2015-01-01 07:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 07:25:00 UTC"
#>  [91] "2015-01-01 07:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 07:35:00 UTC"
#>  [93] "2015-01-01 07:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 07:45:00 UTC"
#>  [95] "2015-01-01 07:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 07:55:00 UTC"
#>  [97] "2015-01-01 08:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 08:05:00 UTC"
#>  [99] "2015-01-01 08:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 08:15:00 UTC"
#> [101] "2015-01-01 08:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 08:25:00 UTC"
#> [103] "2015-01-01 08:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 08:35:00 UTC"
#> [105] "2015-01-01 08:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 08:45:00 UTC"
#> [107] "2015-01-01 08:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 08:55:00 UTC"
#> [109] "2015-01-01 09:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 09:05:00 UTC"
#> [111] "2015-01-01 09:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 09:15:00 UTC"
#> [113] "2015-01-01 09:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 09:25:00 UTC"
#> [115] "2015-01-01 09:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 09:35:00 UTC"
#> [117] "2015-01-01 09:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 09:45:00 UTC"
#> [119] "2015-01-01 09:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 09:55:00 UTC"
#> [121] "2015-01-01 10:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 10:05:00 UTC"
#> [123] "2015-01-01 10:10:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 10:15:00 UTC"
#> [125] "2015-01-01 10:20:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 10:25:00 UTC"
#> [127] "2015-01-01 10:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 10:35:00 UTC"
#> [129] "2015-01-01 10:40:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 10:45:00 UTC"
#> [131] "2015-01-01 10:50:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 10:55:00 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-07 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that is also my thought of 'leading zero' and make all of them in the same format with the same total width as you said. Thank you so much for your help!