Add 0 before a single digit to a column
I have dataframe with several columns like this with str character
df$A <- c("1, 26, 61", "2, 3", "2, 68", "2", "2, 3", "3, 11")
I want to add 0 before a single-digit only
I have tried these codes but I am not getting desired output like this
output= "01, 26, 61", "02, 03", "02, 68", "02", "02, 03", "03, 11"


df$A <- sprintf("%02s",df$A)
df$A <- str_pad(df$A, width=2, pad=0)
stringr::str_pad(df, 2, side="left", pad="0")


Possibly helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros

library(stringr)

str_replace_all(df$A, "\\d+", \(x) str_pad(x, width = 2, "left", pad = "0"))
# [1] "01, 26, 61"   "02, 03"   "02, 68"   "02"   "02, 03"   "03, 11"


Thanks for your time. It really works. Can you please explain in detail like what (x) does?

@PawanRaghav Sure. The third argument of str_replace_all() can be a function that takes matches. In this case, we capture digits and pass it to this function. \(x) is shorthand notation for creating an anonymous function that was introduced in R 4.1.1. This unnamed function takes the digits matched by the regular expression pattern and passes it to str_pad() to pad them as you requested.

Maybe you can try
> x <- c("1, 26, 61", "2, 3", "2, 68", "2", "2, 3", "3, 11")

> gsub("\\b(\\d)\\b", "0\\1", x)
[1] "01, 26, 61" "02, 03"     "02, 68"     "02"         "02, 03"
[6] "03, 11"


Hi Thomas thank you for your code. It really worked and solved my problem. Can you please explain a little bit?

@PawanRaghav \\b(\\d)\\b captures the single digits, and 0\\1 pads a 0 prior to that captured group (represented by \\1)

Thats great. I have an question, like how do I modify the code for 2 digits only?

@PawanRaghav what is the desired output for 2 digits only?

"1, 026, 061" "2, 3" "2, 068" "2" "2, 3" "3, 011" should be the output.

@PawanRaghav then you use \\b(\\d{2})\\b

Splitting each string, padding, and then pasting back together again will allow a degree of flexibility, at the cost of some more complexity:
A <- c("1, 26, 61", "2, 3", "2, 68", "2", "2, 3", "3, 11")
sapply(strsplit(A, ",\\s+"),
       \(x) paste(sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x)), collapse=", "))

## or as Thomas notes in the comments, if the comma separated output is sufficient:
sapply(strsplit(A, ",\\s+"),
       \(x) toString(sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x))))

Both giving:
##[1] "01, 26, 61" "02, 03"     "02, 68"     "02"         "02, 03"    
##[6] "03, 11"  


or you can use toString for shorter code
